# Define variable relationships and dynamically update variables

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to define a relationship between 3 variables first and then later when I have filled two of the variables with a number, I would like to extract the value of the last value.

For example:

```
a * b == c; (* Somehow define this *)
Attributes[GetValues] = {HoldAll}
GetValues[known_] := With[known, {a, b, c}]

GetValues[{a = 2, b = 3}] (* => {2, 3, 6} *)
GetValues[{a = 2, c = 10}] (* => {2, 5, 10} *)
GetValues[{b = 10, c = 10}] (* => {1, 10, 10} *)
```

Only two of the variables will be defined at a time and there should always be only one possible value for the last variable, if the other two values are valid.

You could possible to this with either `Solve` or `Reduce`, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For very simple examples like your example you could use something like this:

```
GetValues[known_] := With[known, {a, b, c} /. First[Solve[a*b == c]]]
```

This works due to the undocumented (?) feature that `Solve` will work without a second argument and if only one unkown is left it seems to always be doing "the expected thing", e.g.:

```
Solve[23*x+5==6]
```

I'd be careful if I'd build something on that feature, though. With only minimal additional effort you can also construct a call to `Solve` explicitly solving for the remaining variable, which then uses documented behavior (I also added some protection from external definitions of `a`, `b` or `c`):

```
ClearAll[GetValues];
Attributes[GetValues] = {HoldAll};
GetValues[known_] := Block[{a, b, c},With[known,
  {a, b, c} /. Solve @@ {a*b == c, Cases[{a, b, c}, _Symbol]}
]]
```

Either way: Depending on your requirements and real world relations, might want to add some checking of whether everything worked as intended...